# haystack and Solr locally

Tags: python, django

I have a Django site that using haystack and Solr. In the live environment (Ubuntu) this is fine.

However I want to do some testing locally on my mac. What are the recommendations for running Solr on the Mac for testing within the context of Python. Is there something like virtualenv for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [Whoosh](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html#whoosh) with Django/Haystack locally. It is easy to use and requires no dedicated server.